# Ошибка - "Не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в Гитлаб"

Tags: git, gitlab

Создал репозиторий на гитлаб, затем инициализировал Гит в своем проекте на компьютере. Столкнулся с ошибкой. " не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://.........» "

```
подсказка: Обновления были отклонены, так как внешний репозиторий содержит
подсказка: изменения, которых у вас нет в вашем локальном репозитории.
подсказка: Обычно, это связанно с тем, что кто-то уже отправил изменения в 
подсказка: то же место. Перед повторной отправкой ваших изменений, вам нужно
подсказка: забрать и слить изменения из внешнего репозитория себе
подсказка: (например, с помощью «git pull …»).
подсказка: Для дополнительной информации смотрите «Note about fast-forwards»
подсказка: в «git push --help».
```

Помогите пожалуйста, боюсь ошибиться со своими дальнейшими действиями...
При создании репозитория на гитлабе, автоматически был создан файл readme. При инициализации локального репозитория и создании коммита встает ошибка. Дело в этом файле? Он пошел первым коммитом при создании репозитория на сервисе

Comment: Вы хотите локальный проект выгрузить? Тогда создавайте чистый репозиторий без readme и т.п. чтоб он был абсолютно пустым

Comment: Запусти вначале `git pull --rebase origin master` или при выгрузке `git push -f`.